# How to override cx-item-counter in spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to customize the product increment or decrement quantity from OOTB to have my own implementation. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

I tried to create a new component in my custom store and used the extend feature of angular as this is not a cms component.

My Custom component is not getting rendered instead it renders the cx-item-counter.

```html
import { ItemCounterComponent } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import {
  Component,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'custom-item-counter',
  templateUrl: './cart-counter.component.html',

export class CartCounter extends ItemCounterComponent {

}
```

Is there any way I can achieve to override this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, have a look at how the component is setup in the official spartacus repo:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/release/4.0.0/projects/storefrontlib/src/shared/components/item-counter

I imagine you would need to create a module and have the module import the component. To render your custom version, you would need to use  in the component that you import your custom component in.

Wherever you want your custom module/component to be imported, replace ItemCounterModule.

Currently the add to cart component imports it directly:
https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/tree/release/4.0.0/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/cart/add-to-cart

If you are not overriding the add to cart component, then I am not sure you can achieve what you are looking to achieve, since the spartacus version of the item counter is being imported directly. You might need to extend the add to cart component as well so that you can change  to .

This would be my approach. I have not tested it. Perhaps this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: I have achieved it by importing the model in the component. as 

import '../model/augmented-core.model';

So it works fine now